# Prevent disk spinup by regular directory read access

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, cache

I have a hard drive which is configured to spin down on inactivity.

Unfortunately, a regularly (~every 15 min) occuring directory read access wakes up the disk from its slumber. When there is no write access to the disk, I would like to have Linux cache the directory contents indefinitely, in order to prevent disk spinup entirely. How would I do this?

I already disabled `atime` by mounting the disk with `noexec,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=20,noatime,nodiratime`.

`fatrace` shows the following log when the disk is being accessed:

```
22:00:06.654630 perl(10477): RO /media/mydisk/backups
22:00:06.654630 perl(10477): R /media/mydisk/backups
22:00:06.654775 perl(10477): C /media/mydisk/backups
22:00:06.654807 perl(10477): RO /media/mydisk/backups
22:00:06.654807 perl(10477): R /media/mydisk/backups
22:00:06.654861 perl(10477): C /media/mydisk/backups
22:00:06.655326 perl(10477): RO /media/mydisk/backups/Backup 1
22:00:06.655803 perl(10477): C /media/mydisk/backups/Backup 1
22:00:06.656219 perl(10477): RO /media/mydisk/backups/Backup 2
22:00:06.656622 perl(10477): C /media/mydisk/backups/Backup 2
```

Note that not every access causes the drive to spin up. From what I observe it seems like the drive is woken approximately once an hour. I suspect this is because the directory cache expires?

Running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4, Linux Kernel 5.3.0-51-generic, drive's filesystem is `ext4`

Comment: The Linux kernel can be configured to never reclaim the memory used for dentries and inodes - see `vfs_cache_pressure=0` in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#vfs-cache-pressure). But I really couldn't say whether it's likely to prevent your disk from spinning up at all.

Comment: try lvmcache on a small ssd